# Is there a way to insert cookies into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I need to match up a users name with a value inside a database, so I want to insert the users name that is saved in a cookie. The function is pretty simple. The cookie is stored correctly and I can echo it. My insert script also works cause I can insert other things. But for some reason I cannot insert a cookies value.

This is pretty much what I'm trying to do:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
or die('error');
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Gallery (username) VALUES('$username')";
$data1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query1) or die('error1');
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Is there something I'm missing? I tried using sessions, but no luck.

I also made the cookie accessible throughout the whole domain.

Comment: Please escape your input (using `mysql_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])`), otherwise you're wide open to SQL Injection (very bad).

Comment: Is `$username = $_COOKIE['username'];` evaluating and giving $username a value? Is there an error message you see?

Comment: Yeah it evaluates. I've echoed $username and get the proper value. Is the code suppose to work? The code is suppose to run when a file is submitted. I've replaced the cookie with a simple string, and the string is inserted. But when I replace it with the cookie, the cookie value isn't inserted.

Comment: the table name is `Gallery` or `gallery` ?

Comment: Don't `die()` with 'error1'. That's useless, you'll lose any error message generated by the query failure. Instead, do `die(mysql_error())` which'll tell you why the query failed.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two problems here.

1. You copy the value of the cookie to a variable called `$user` but use a variable called `$username` to try to insert data into the database
2. You don't perform any kind of sanity check on the cookie data (which is data provided by the browser and thus tainted) before using in an SQL query. This is an invitation to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Number 1 was actually a typo when I was writing the question. In my script they match up, and still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try changing your query to this...

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Gallery (username) VALUES(" . mysql_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']) . ")";
```